# captureOutput(_:didOutput:from:) delegate method not called on one particular iPhone XR

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, coreml

I am trying to capture the camera frames (CVPixelBuffers) using the `captureOutput(:didOutput:from:)` delegate method. For context, these frames are sent to CoreML to classify the image.

**Issue:**
Works on all iOS devices I could possibly get my hands on so far except for the iPhone XR. By works, I mean to state that the buffers are captured on all devices except for one particular XR oddly.

**Specs:**

1. iPhone XR
2. Issue noted in iOS 16.3 and 16.7 (have not tried other iOS versions)

**What I have tried and blockers:**

1. Purchased a refurbished XR from Amazon and it works on that device. It also worked on a colleague's XR.
2. Unfortunately, I don't have continuous access to the XR where the delegate method was not fired as it is a personal phone that belongs to a client.
3. There seems to be no error thrown by Xcode as well - I would expect an error stating the buffers could not be captured but unfortunately, Apple's documentation only identifies two delegate methods (one being the `captureOutput` and the other related to dropped frames)

Here is the code where I define the view controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Vision


class TestCameraViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var bufferSize: CGSize = .zero
    private var previewView: UIView = UIView()
    private var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer! = nil

    private let session = AVCaptureSession()
    private let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    private var currentVideoDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
                
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
        setupAVCapture()
        startCaptureSession()
    }
        
    func setupView() {
        previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(previewView)
        previewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    func setupAVCapture() {

        var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
        
        // Select a video device, make an input
        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back).devices.first
        
        if videoDevice == nil {
            print("Device Does Not Exist, properties: nil, level: .error, skipAnalytics: true")
            return
        }

        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!)

        } catch {
            print("Could not create video device input")
            return
        }
        
        session.beginConfiguration()
        session.sessionPreset = .vga640x480 // Model image size is smaller.
        
        // Add a video input
        guard session.canAddInput(deviceInput) else {
            session.commitConfiguration()
            print("Could not add video device input")
            return
        }
        
        session.addInput(deviceInput)
        
        if session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
            session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
            videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
            videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)]
            videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: .global())
            
        } else {
            session.commitConfiguration()
            print("Could not add video data output.")
            return
        }
                
        let captureConnection = videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)
        captureConnection?.isEnabled = true
        
        do {
            try  videoDevice!.lockForConfiguration()
            let dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions((videoDevice?.activeFormat.formatDescription)!)
            bufferSize.width = CGFloat(dimensions.width)
            bufferSize.height = CGFloat(dimensions.height)
            videoDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print("Could not lock video device configuration.")
            return
        }
        
        session.commitConfiguration()
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.currentVideoDevice = videoDevice
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        if previewLayer != nil {
            previewLayer.frame = previewView.bounds
            previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        }
    }
    
    func startCaptureSession() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.session.startRunning()
        }
    }
        
    // Clean up capture setup
    func teardownAVCapture() {
        session.stopRunning()
        previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        previewLayer = nil
    }
}
```

And here is the code where I conform to the delegate (which is not fired on the XR)

```
extension TestCameraViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        
        //NOT CALLED on one particular iPhone XR physical device
        
        guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate suggestions and next steps or potential flaws in the code that might lead to this behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure `setupAVCapture()` is succeeding? Have you stepped through the code?  How about not setting `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange` or trying video range, `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange`? Try skipping all the configuration committing stuff, try a different dispatch queue, try dumping the `AVPreviewLayer` etc.